# C-style pointer/array casting in Swift?

Tags: c, arrays, swift, pointers, casting

Is there any way I can cast an array of different integer sizes to another array type?

For example, in C, I can do:

```c
unsigned char byteArray[] = { 0x1, 0x5, 0xF, 0x3, 0xA5, 0x3, 0x8, 0x8, 0xAB };
unsigned long long *largeArray = (unsigned long long *)(byteArray);
```

which would make `largeArray` equal to `{ 0x80803A5030F0501, 0x51B76EB7140024AB }`.

Is there any similar thing in Swift? For example, something like:

```swift
let byteArray: [UInt8] = [0x1, 0x5, 0xF, 0x3, 0xA5, 0x3, 0x8, 0x8, 0xAB]
let largeArray = [UInt64](byteArray)
```

I know it is possible to do programmatically, I was just wondering if there's a built in method before I delve into making my own thing that will cast them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In general casting a character array to an array of an integer type with higher rank results in undefined behavior due to the alignment.

Comment: You're right. I'm doing this for a BigInteger library, and I want to be able to initialize my BigNumber struct with any type of array. My struct represents the number as an array of UInt64's but I want it to be constructable from maybe a UInt32 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s assume the `byteArray` had eight bytes in it. You could do:

```
let byteArray: [UInt8] = [0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7]

let value = byteArray.withUnsafeBytes { 
    $0.bindMemory(to: UInt64.self)[0].littleEndian    // or .bigEndian
}
```

Resulting in:

```
0x0706050403020100     // or 0x0001020304050607 if you use bigEndian
```

Or, if you had enough bytes for multiple `UInt64`, you could do:

```
let longByteArray: [UInt8] = [
    0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7,
    0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf
]

let values = longByteArray.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.bindMemory(to: UInt64.self)
}.map {
    $0.littleEndian       // or .bigEndian
}
```

Resulting in

```
[0x0706050403020100, 0x0f0e0d0c0b0a0908] // or [0x0001020304050607, 0x08090a0b0c0d0e0f] if you use bigEndian
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.